# Custom Request não redireciona Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Estou implementando um sistema e realizei a criação do um request através do comando:

`php artisan make:request PreventivaRequest`

Coloquei minhas regras no Request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Tecnologia\Preventivas\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StorePreventiva extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Redirect route when errors occur.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectRoute = 'preventiva.novo';

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'nome_computador' => 'required',
            'ip' => 'required',
            'so_id' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

E utilizei o request em meu controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Tecnologia\Preventivas;

use Aplicredi\Repositories\Sistema\Usuarios\IUserRepository;
use Aplicredi\Repositories\Tecnologia\Preventiva\IPreventivaRepository;
use Aplicredi\Repositories\Tecnologia\Preventiva\IPreventivaSoRepository;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tecnologia\Preventivas\Requests\StorePreventiva;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tecnologia\Preventivas\Requests\UpdatePreventiva;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

/**
 * Class PreventivasController
 * @package Http\Controllers\Tecnologia\Preventivas
 */
class PreventivasController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var IPreventivaRepository
     */
    protected $preventivaRepository;

    /**
     * @var IPreventivaSoRepository
     */
    protected $preventivaSoRepository;

    /**
     * @var IUserRepository
     */
    protected $userRepository;

    /**
     * PreventivasController constructor.
     * @param IPreventivaRepository $preventivaRepository
     * @param IPreventivaSoRepository $preventivaSoRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        IPreventivaRepository $preventivaRepository,
        IPreventivaSoRepository $preventivaSoRepository,
        IUserRepository $userRepository
    )
    {
        $this->preventivaRepository = $preventivaRepository;
        $this->preventivaSoRepository = $preventivaSoRepository;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function novo()
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->find(Auth::user()->id);

        return view('Tecnologia.Preventivas.novo', compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * @param StorePreventiva $request
     */
    public function store(StorePreventiva $request)
    {

    }

    /**
     * @param UpdatePreventiva $request
     */
    public function update(UpdatePreventiva $request)
    {

    }
}
```

Porém quando eu realizo o post para o action store ele me retorna uma Exception:

```
Illuminate \ Validation \ ValidationException
The given data failed to pass validation.
```

E não faz o redirecionamento para o formulário para que eu possa exibir os erros de validação do mesmo.

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610845/laravel-validator-throws-an-exception-instead-of-redirecting-back

Comment: Um outro fator, se cria um Request com um nome e a classe com outro Nome, sempre tente criar tudo com o mesmo nome ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic desculpe mas não encontrei relação no link que informou. Realmente se eu estivesse a fazer as validações no próprio controller eu poderia utilizar o `Redirect::back()`, porém estou utilizando o FormRequest, outro detalhe que você me citou sobre o nome da request e da classe, o que isto iria influenciar?

Comment: Resolvi a situação, estava utilizando o biblioteca https://github.com/filp/whoops e de alguma forma isto alterou o comportamento padrão do Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um detalhe que eu não havia mencionado (até porque não achei que teria relação) era de que eu estava utilizando os Exceptions do [Whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) junto ao Laravel 5.4.

De alguma forma o Whoops alterou o comportamento padrão de retorno do Laravel ao utilizar um Custom Request.

Para resolver a situação e continuar a utilizar o Whoops alterei o método render() do arquivo `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` da seguinte forma:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if (!$exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        if (config('app.debug') && config('app.env') == 'local') {
            return $this->renderExceptionWithWhoops($request, $exception);
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Desta forma o Laravel voltou a trabalhar corretamente, retornando e redirecionando em caso de não validação do formulário.